Chaining of multiple LINQ conditional Orderby(Descending) and ThenBy(Descending) clauses
I've encountered a problem when trying to implement sorting logic:
Imagine a Person model that consists of multiple fields, alike:
public class Person
{
    public string firstName {  get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOT {  get; set; }
    // ...
}

and a couple of persons:
ObservableCollection<Person> Persons = new();

var jane = new Person()
{
    firstName = "Jane",
    lastName = "Doe",
    DOT = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2002")
};

var john = new Person()
{
    firstName = "John",
    lastName = "Doe",
    DOT = DateTime.Parse("31/12/2002")
};

var george = new Person()
{
    firstName = "George",
    lastName = "Orwell",
    DOT = DateTime.Parse("25/06/1903")
};

// Add persons to a collection:
Persons.add(jane);
Persons.add(john);
Persons.add(george);

Now, multiple persons are being stored in a collection and should be sorted. However,
the user should have the possibility to choose for which field an ascending or descending sorting should be applied, in which order and if at all.
A couple of examples of person sortings:

Scenario 1: FirstName (Asc)
Scenario 2: FirstName (Asc)  + LastName (Desc)
Scenario 3: FirstName (Desc) + DOT (Asc)
Scenario 4: FirstName (Desc) + LastName (Asc) + DOT (Asc)
Scenario 5: DOT (Asc) + FirstName (Desc)
Scenario 6: LastName (Desc) + FirstName (Desc) + DOT (Asc)
...

The order orders the precendence, therefore the first chosen sorting has higher precedence than the following sortings.
Now, as I see it, with LINQ one could do something like the following:

Scenario 1:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderBy(x => x.firstName)
           .ToList()
);


Scenario 2:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderBy(x => x.firstName)
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.lastName)
           .ToList()
);


Scenario 3:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderByDescending(x => x.firstName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.DOT)
           .ToList()
);


Scenario 4:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderByDescending(x => x.firstName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.lastName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.DOT)
           .ToList()
);


Scenario 5:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderBy(x => x.DOT)
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.firstName)
           .ToList()
);


Scenario 6:

Persons = new(
    Persons.OrderByDescending(x => x.lastName)
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.firstName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.DOT)
           .ToList()
);

My question now is:
How does one bundle those orders in one clean function?
How can I dynamically choose to either order by asc. or desc. while for example traversing through the list of sortings?
UPDATE:
For clarity, I try to give an actual example:
Imagine the sorting is controlled by buttons. When a button is pressed an associated boolean state is changed, that represents the respective ascending/descending state of the Person field, e.g.
public class ButtonObject
{
    public string? ButtonText { get; set; }
    public IRelayCommand? ButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public bool? ButtonIsVisible { get; set; } = true;
    public bool? IsOrderedAscending { get; set; } = true;
    public string? ButtonGlyph { get; set; }
}

So, according to FirstName, LastName, DOT the following three buttons would be created, that also use certain backing fields:

// Up- and Down-Button Glyphs from Google Material Icons:
private const string Keyboard_arrow_down = "\ue313";
public const string Keyboard_arrow_up = "\ue316";

private const string 

[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<ButtonObject> _buttons = new();

// in the Constructor of the ViewModel:
{

_firstNameButton = new ButtonObject
{
    ButtonText = "FirstName",
    ButtonCommand = OrderByFirstNameCommand,
    ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down,
};

_lastNameButton = new ButtonObject
{
    ButtonText = "LastName",
    ButtonCommand = OrderByLastNameCommand,
    ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down,
};

_DOTButton = new ButtonObject
{
    ButtonText = "DOT",
    ButtonCommand = OrderByDOTCommand,
    ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down,
};

// add all buttons to the collection:
Buttons.Add(_firstNameButton);
Buttons.Add(_lastNameButton);
Buttons.Add(_DOTButton);
}

Now, imagine the buttons can be dynamically added to a corresponding CollectionView in the View, therefore the order could be:
<------------------>  <------------------>  <------------------> 
| FirstName Button |  | LastName Button  |  | DOT Button       |
<------------------>  <------------------>  <------------------>

or it could be:
<------------------>  <------------------>  <------------------> 
| LastNameButton   |  | FirstNameButton  |  | DOT Button       |
<------------------>  <------------------>  <------------------>

or even:
<------------------>  <------------------> 
| DOT Button       |  | LastName Button  |
<------------------>  <------------------>

When one is pressing on the buttons the ascending boolean property is changed and the corresponding Glyph as well to match either ascending or descending order:
[RelayCommand]
private void OnSortByFirstName()
{
    var _sortByFirstNameButton = Buttons[0];
    if (_sortByFirstNameButton.IsSortedAscending)
    {
        _sortByFirstNameButton.IsSortedAscending = false;
        _sortByFirstNameButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_up;
    }
    else
    {
        _sortByFirstNameButton.IsSortedAscending = true;
        _sortByFirstNameButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down;
    }

    UpdateSorting();
}

[RelayCommand]
private void OnSortByLastName()
{
    var _sortByLastNameButton = Buttons[1];
    if (_sortByLastNameButton.IsSortedAscending)
    {
        _sortByLastNameButton.IsSortedAscending = false;
        _sortByLastNameButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_up;
    }
    else
    {
        _sortByLastNameButton.IsSortedAscending = true;
        _sortByLastNameButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down;
    }
    UpdateSorting();
}

[RelayCommand]
private void OnSortByDOT()
{
    var _sortByDOTButton = Buttons[2];
    if (_sortByDOTButton.IsSortedAscending)
    {
        _sortByDOTButton.IsSortedAscending = false;
        _sortByDOTButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_up;
    }
    else
    {
        _sortByDOTButton.IsSortedAscending = true;
        _sortByDOTButton.ButtonGlyph = Keyboard_arrow_down;
    }
    UpdateSorting();
}

Now, the UpdateSorting() function is the one I'm worried about. It needs to take the order and state of all the buttons into account and therefore rearrange the persons.
If there were only one button, it could be something like this:
private void UpdateSorting()
{
    if (Buttons[0].IsSortedAscending)
    {
        Persons = new(
            Persons.OrderBy(x => x.firstName).ToList()
            );
    }
    else
    {
        Persons = new(
            Persons.OrderByDescending(x => x.firstName).ToList()
            );
    }
}

However, for two buttons the code bloats already up to the following:
private void UpdateSorting()
{
    if (Buttons[0].IsSortedAscending)
    {
        if (Buttons[1].IsSortedAscending)
        {
            Persons = new(
                Persons
                    .OrderBy(x => x.firstName)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.lastName)
                    .ToList()
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Persons = new(
                Persons
                    .OrderBy(x => x.firstName)
                    .ThenByDescending(x => x.lastName)
                    .ToList()
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Buttons[1].IsSortedAscending)
        {
            Persons = new(
                Persons
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.firstName)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.lastName)
                    .ToList()
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Persons = new(
                Persons
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.firstName)
                    .ThenByDescending(x => x.lastName)
                    .ToList()
            );
        }
    }
}

With every additional button, the number of necessary if/else statements doubles: that can't be idiomatic or the best solution.

Possibly you can use System.Linq.Dynamic

It is unclear what exactly you want to do. Can you show some examples of the code that you want to write, using this "one clean function" that you are trying to create?

Every LINQ operation returns a new query. You can append Where, OrderBy or ThenBy as needed, based on parameters. You don't have to specify all operators at once. You can write eg if(somParam) { query=query.Where();} if (someOrder){ query=query.OrderBy(...);}

Another optimization is to store the Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> needed by OrderBy as a property of ButtonObject, and just use it to build the query. The sorting code can just loop over the buttons and apply the correct operator and function without having to know which field is used for sorting

You can try this code:
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> DynamicSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, params (Func<T,object> selector, SortOrder sortOrder)[] parameters)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = null;
    foreach(var p in parameters)
    {
        if(result == null)
        {
            result = p.sortOrder == SortOrder.Asc ? input.OrderBy(p.selector) : input.OrderByDescending(p.selector);
        }
        else
        {
            result = p.sortOrder == SortOrder.Asc ? result.ThenBy(p.selector) : result.ThenByDescending(p.selector);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

You call this method e.g. by
persons.DynamicSort(
     (new Func<Person,object>(x => x.firstName), SortOrder.Asc),
     (new Func<Person,object>(x => x.lastName), SortOrder.Desc),
     (new Func<Person,object>(x => x.DOT), SortOrder.Asc));

This will translate to the LINQ query
persons.OrderBy(x => x.firstName).ThenByDescending(x => x.lastName).ThenBy(x => x.DIT);

This method is fully developed by now. You should add some checks if input is null or if the array has zero elements. Moreover, because the selector methods have object as a return type, value types will be boxed. This means that the garbage collection has more work to do and is not good for performance. But maybe this is a good starting point for you.
Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6neHxr

Looks ok to me; the params argument would have to be populated from the GUI.

This works only on IEnumerable, not IQueryable, and even there it will cause boxing of value types. It will fail with EF or any other provider beyond LINQ-to-Objects. Fixing it is easy, use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable, DON'T use object anywhere and use Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>

@PanagiotisKanavos I was thinking of Func<TSource,TKey> first. But when you want to order by a string and then by an int, this will not work. That's why I chose object as return type despite its disadvantage. Also, from OP's example it was clear he wants to sort an ObservableCollection which is stored locally in memory and does not use EF.
